# How to get password from ansible vault to be used as variable?

Tags: variables, ansible, passwords, ansible-vault

I have the following ansible role:

```
- name: Get latest code from repository
  git:
    repo: 'https://{{ username }}:{{ password }}@{{ repository }}'
    dest: "{{ destination }}"
    force: yes
```

While `username` and `repository` can be variables, I am puzzled over how to retrieve `password` from ansible vault. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a YAML file in `vars/` folder (it can be in any folder, `host_vars` or `group_vars` are also valid, depending of what type of variables you're keeping) containing your variables. Let's call it `vars/git-data.yml`. Then, encrypt it using Vault with:

```sh
ansible-vault encrypt vars/git-data.yml
```

A password will be required. Remember it.

Then, you have two options for including your variables while running your playbook:

- Option A: Including them in your playbook:

```yaml
--- 
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_files:
    -  vars/git-data.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Print variable
      ansible.builtin.debug:
       msg: "{{ username }}"
```

- Option B: Referring them while you call `ansible-playbook`:

```sh
ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass -e @vars/git-data.yml cloning-repository.yml
```

Vault's password will be asked. You can also use `--vault-password-file ${file}` or `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE` environment variable indicating a password containing a password file.

Best regards.

Comment: Is encrypting a .yml which contains the username/password the only option? How about `ansible-vault create --vault-id myid@vault-secret group_vars/myid/myid_vault.yml`?

Comment: `ansible-vault create` creates the file if it doesn't exist. Vault ID enables you to use multiple passwords for the file you're encrypting. But yeah, AFAIK, it's the only option. Storing it into `group_vars/myid` won't work, since `myid` should be your group's name defined in your inventory.

Comment: Also, if you're using `host_vars/` or `group_vars/` to store your variables, Ansible automatically will try to load them based by host or group on your inventory. Again, it kinda depends on how you're organizing your project.

Comment: `myid` is a group in my previous comment. My question was if `ansible-vault encrypt group_vars/mygroup/git-data.yml` is the only option? Can I use `ansible-vault create --vault-id myid@vault-secret group_vars/mygroup/mygroup_vault.yml` and get the `password` from `mygroup_vault.yml`?

Comment: Sure. Vault's agnostic and doesn't care where's your playbook's reading its variables from. You can even pass variables files with `-e @path/to-variable/file.yml`.

Comment: How is it different from `ansible-vault encrypt group_vars/mygroup/git-data.yml`? How do I achieve my objective with `ansible-vault create ...`?

Comment: `ansible-vault create ...` creates a encrypted file with Vault. You can create an YAML file and encrypt it later with `ansible-vault encrypt` with no problem whatsover. Imagine Vault as a mechanism to secure sensitive data in Ansible's files through encryption.

Storing your variables in `group_vars/`, `host_vars/`, `vars/` or any other file, will change variable precedence, for instance. Also, that variable will be set for all hosts in that group if you set inside the `group_vars/` folder.